# powermail validation issue - typo3

Tags: typo3, powermail

Hi I have to show the validation error message when validation fails.But powermail returns an error message Validation failed while trying to call  ....createAction();
   How to redirect the page when validation fails?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're writing about the serverside validation in powermail. There is nothing special - it's a normal Extbase validation behaviour. This means, that the validators will be checked before createAction() or confirmationAction(). If a validation fails, extbase will redirect the user to the last working action - in this case formAction() - and should show the errors above the rendered form.
So your problem is, that the form is rendered again but there are no error messages?

Comment: I need to show the redirected page with the validation error message.